Machine Learning Approach to detect Function Splits
Down there is a cartoon of my problem. The function clearly splits into two pieces. For a human this is easy to identify, however, how would a machine learning method solve this kind of problem? If I use simple regression, the identified function would certainly go through the middle of both functions, which is not very helpful.
I want also a method for the higher dimensional case, where a human can't plot things and easily identify the splitting region/functions. Any suggestions on this kind of problem would be helpful.


Could you please say more about your problem? Do you mean that you have two groups , one represented by black and the other by blue?

Ignore the color for the time being and let's say there's just data points represented by the circles. I want to use a machine learning methode which identifies the two functions automatically. Is this even possible? Every textbook machine learning approach assumes that there is only one function within the data. Regression would therefore lead to a middling function which is basically a tradeoff between the two obv functions.

Please clarify what you have and what you want. Do you essentially just have the circles, no lines and no colors, and want a method to essentially draw the lines? That will be very hard, because how should any method (humans included) understand whether a given circle over $x=1$ to $x=5$ belongs to the trajectory currently colored blue or the one currently colored black? Or are you actually interested in change point detection for time series (lots of work in this direction done), as your blue curve seems to suggest?

You will also need to be more specific about your "higher dimensional case:" what are the dimensions of the range and of the domain and what exactly might a "split" mean when the domain's dimension is 2 or greater?  Also, why aren't you just asking about how to determine whether there's a portion of the domain in which the difference of two functions is non-zero?  What is special about comparing one function to another?

I should've left out the colors. This is a usual regression problem setting, where you have data $x_i, y_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ and want to find a function $f(x)$ that fits the data. However, in my case the data is generated by two functions $f_1(x), f_2(x)$ and not one. Is there any ml method which can identify these two functions (also in higher dimensions)?

If you have a bunch of data, a model of the full distribution, such as with multiple quantile regressions, would be able to show multimodality. Is that among the lines of what you would want?

Look at the derivatives of the two functions and fit a linear model on them. Good fit? Type 1. Bad fit? Type 2.

If all you’re trying to do is fit some kind of flexible family of functions to some data, then splines, kernel regression, and MARS all seem viable. But if you care specifically about partitioning a function into some number of parts, maybe this is more like clustering.

@Dave Multimodal distribution seems to be the right keyword. I am only familiar with unimodal fitting tho. Do you have good references for this topic?

The multimodality is more incidental than anything, at least with regards to what I have in mind. My idea is to run flexible quantile regression models, perhaps using spline features, perhaps using a quantile regression neural network. Then the models estimate conditional quantiles or full conditional distributions, rather than conditional means. You are correct that a model of conditional means will draw a line down the middle of that split between the blue and black portions of the plot. Modeling quantiles won't have to do that, depending on the quantile (and the data).
